# Insert, Delete and Query Google App Engine Datastore using JSP

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, gql

I am new to appengine and JSP. I have seen google Help for datatsore, but i can't understand that. Is there any tutorial or someone who explains insertion, deletion and Query appengine datastore.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: how do you want to do it? using JPA, JDO, the native API?

Comment: Using API's, i am not familiar with JDO or JPA

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've learnt to use GAE DataStore with [Dan Pilone's videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583897/using-low-level-api-for-datastore-in-google-app-engine-is-it-bad) on O'Reilly media, he uses JPA, but doesn't assume prior knowledge of it.

About the low level API, I [found this](http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/03/introduction-to-working-with-app-engine%E2%80%99s-low-level-datastore-api/) with a google search. However, my suggestion would be to learn a higher level abstraction rather than the low level API. In addition to JPA and JDO there are other frameworks such as [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/).