# Accessing the GAE Datastore: Use JDO, JPA or the low-level API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Any recommendations on how to best access the Google App Engine Datastore?  Via JDO, JPA or the native API?

The obvious advantages of JDO/JPA are portability to other database engines, but apart from that, any reason not to work directly with the Datastore API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know much about JPA, but I went with JDO, and if you're new to it I can say that it has a pretty steep learning curve and a lot of extraneous stuff that doesn't apply to GAE.  What you do win is [owned relationships,](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html) which allow you to have classes with actual references to each other instead of just datastore IDs.  There are also some useful things JDO does via annotations, such as the @Element(dependent = "true") annotation, which saves you quite a bit of work as it allows you to delete a parent object and JDO will delete all its children.  In general, the GAE docs miss a lot of things that you need to know to use JDO effectively, so I would say that its crucial to read the datanucleus docs, and pay particular attention to fetch groups.

You can also find a large collection of succinct examples for JDO and JPA that address almost every conceivable scenario [here.](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/org/datanucleus/test/)

Finally I would look at the Objectify and Twig, two apparently popular alternative frameworks, which were mentioned in a [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394280/looking-for-opinions-on-using-objectify-appengine-instead-of-jdo-in-gae-j) when I was also trying to make this decision.

On a side note, as for portability to other databases, I think worrying about portability on GAE is a bit misguided.  As much as Google wants us to think that GAE code is portable, I think its a pipe dream.  You will end up coding to target the particular mix of APIs that Google offers, a mix that you probably won't see anywhere else, and also coding around GAE's many limitations and idiosyncracies, so I would forget about portability as a factor for settling on a data-access API.  In fact, if I could remake my decision on this matter, I think I would use a data-access framework that's built specifically for GAE, such as objectify.

Answer (score 6):

The low-level Datastore API is not designed to be used directly, but rather to provide an API for other frameworks to interact with the datastore.

> This package contains a low-level API to the datastore that is intended primarily for framework authors. Applications authors should consider using either the provided JDO or JPA interfaces to the datastore.

([source](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html))

One such framework is [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/), a much simpler interface for the datastore than JDO or JPA, and one that's designed with only the datastore in mind.

Comment: Well for appengine-jruby they recommend datamapper but you cannot use Ruby's serialization functionality (=> memcache) because it's broken for the dm-appengine adapter. Google's App Engine documentation is not really award winning...

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is a matter of taste. An ORM solution (JDO/JPA) is usually the more comfortable one. On the other hand the low-level API allows for full flexiblity, you are not contrained by any limitations of the ORM. Of course you need to write more code and you might want to write your own datastore abstraction layer. But this might become handy if you need to optimize certain things later on.

But of course you can start using JDO/JPA and if you recognize that you need more flexibility you can still refactor certain parts of your code to use the low-level functions. As tempy mentioned, internally references are saved as IDs (same for keys of course).

In general (in the SQL world) a lot of people say that by using the low-level stuff you learn more about your database and therefore get a better feeling for optimizations. There are lots of people who use ORMs but use it very inefficently because they think the ORM does all the work for them. Therefore they run into performance or maintenance issues.

In the end I think either solution is a proper choice if you are not sure. But you should really check out the docs available and read (blog) articles to learn about the best practices, whether you choose JDO/JPA or low-level.

Philip